# Downloading page's HTML returns "\u0003�T���0"

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to get html of this page

`https://ec.europa.eu/esco/portal/skill?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.europa.eu%2Fesco%2Fskill%2F00735755-adc6-4ea0-b034-b8caff339c9f&conceptLanguage=en&full=true`

but for some reason the output that I'm receiving is like that:

`\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0003�T���0\u0010�#�\u000f�\aNM�.+�b�\"v�\u0010�\u0015+��\u001b����[�\u000e���\u001e�\v���`

Here's the code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Host", "ec.europa.eu");
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv,65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0");
    client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
    client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    client.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
    client.Headers.Add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=-(...); escoLanguage=en");

    var output = client.DownloadString(new Uri("https://ec.europa.eu/esco/portal/skill?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.europa.eu%2Fesco%2Fskill%2F00735755-adc6-4ea0-b034-b8caff339c9f&conceptLanguage=en&full=true"));
}
```

Anybody has an idea what's causing that?

I also tried with HTML Agility pack:

```
var url = urls.First();
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
```

but `doc.Text` is `null`

Comment: Try using some `Accept-Encoding` with plain?

Comment: @GenoChen Thanks, removing: ``client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");`` was the solution :)

Comment: `WebRequest` and `HttpClient` can handle compressed stream automatically. You could also use a Custom Control derived from `WebClient` and set the underlying [WebRequest.AutomaticDecompression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression) property to both `GZip` and `Deflate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header "Accept-Encoding: gzip" may send you raw data with **gzip compressed**. You have to decompress the output stream manually. For example,

```
curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" "$url" --output - | gzip -d
```

if you are using a Linux shell.

A better solution is just to remove this header.

Answer (score 1):

Removing: `client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");` was the solution for WebClient

Answer (score 1):

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Headers.Add("Host", "ec.europa.eu");
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv,65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            client.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
            client.Headers.Add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=-(...); escoLanguage=en");
            var downloadStr = client.DownloadData(new Uri("https://ec.europa.eu/esco/portal/skill?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.europa.eu%2Fesco%2Fskill%2F00735755-adc6-4ea0-b034-b8caff339c9f&conceptLanguage=en&full=true"));

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            using (GZipStream g = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(downloadStr), CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {

                g.CopyTo(stream);


            }

            var output=  Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
```

Since the output is compressed, it looks like that so using gzip for uncompressed.